# Polymer - dom-repeat when end binding event?

Tags: javascript, events, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a simple question, because I didn't found this after long search.

**Scenario**:

When a component is loading, I make AJAX call to get data from an API. After call ends i put data in a property that is used for `dom-repeat`. After `dom-repeat` ends rendering I want to do some operation on elements in it. `Read()` is called even before AJAX call ends. Are there others ways to handle that?

Answer (score 4):

You can couple a `dom-change` event and a `debounce` to get what you want.

```
<template is='dom-repeat' items='[[items]]' on-dom-change='_handleDomChangeEvent'>
...
</template>

...

_handleDomChangeEvent: function() {
  this.debounce('domEndEvent', function() {
    // dom-repeat has finished rendering
  }, 100)
}
```

This can be considered brittle - if `dom-change` events fire between spans of more than `100ms` the debouncer will fire twice. For practical purposes however it's unlikely that a DOM change would take that long to complete.

Answer (score 2):

`dom-repeat` will fire `dom-change` event after it update DOM tree.

So you can do something like

```
<template is='dom-repeat' items='[[items]]' on-dom-change='doSomething'>
   ...
</template>
```

See in [document](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomRepeat#events).

Comment: It's works... But it's fired 50 times (in my case). for every single iteration of template. No problem when its low count of rows, but it can be problematic when count of rows will grow up.

Comment: It's weird! I think it should be once (not sure). I also create a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/P3B7hxMSihqTVh7hK0lt?p=preview). It not fire for each iteration.